# Use Shortcuts app to format text

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcuts-app

I have text in this format:

```
Red and green apples
Pear
2 Bananas
red orange
Melon
Grape fruit
```

I need it in this format:

```
c("Red and green apples", "Pear", "2 Bananas", "red orange", "Melon", "Grape fruit")
```

I also have these numbers:

```
1
172
3
183
16
178
68
56
687
576
455
```

Which I need in the format below. Note that this is same format as above except they are numbers so they are missing quotes:

```
c(1, 172, 3, 183, 16, 178, 68, 56, 687, 576, 455)
```

Can I make a shortcut that will automatically convert the text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with regex in Shortcuts.

Here with text:
[image]

and here with integers:
[image]

The code is the same, it’s only the first "Text" action which differ.
More about regex in Shortcuts in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9zo24n/regex_cookbook_for_shortcuts_reusable_regex_to/).

Edit: do not confuse, in the two first "Find Text" in the two screenshots, the `|` in `(\n|$)` is the [vertical bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) character, not a uppercase "i" or a lower case "L".

Edit 2: As asked in the comments by the OP and in the edited question, here is a different version with less constraint in the input (remark: in the first **Replace Text** action, in the field *Replace With*, you should read `"$1",␣`, ie a space should be after the comma, but the screenshot cannot display it, and in the 3rd **Replace Text**, in the field *Find Text*, you should read `(.+),␣`):

[image]

Comment: Hi the above regex only works on lines that have 1 word. How can I get regex to work on lines that have 1 or more words?

Comment: @luciano What are the separator of words? Always a space, or can it be any other punctuation sign? Have you "words" like **ora4nge** in the input (mix of letters and digits)?

Comment: Can be any punctuation sign. Words include letters only.

Comment: @luciano Does my updated answer satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Hi that is very nearly what I'm after, but each line should fall within 1 pair of quotes. Please see my edited question. Thanks!

Comment: @luciano answered with your new requirements.

Answer (score -2):

We want the equivalent of this piece of JS code:

```
"c(" + input_text.split('\n').join(', ') + ")"
```

So the script will be something like this:

Split Text (New Lines) -> Combine Text (Custom separator ", ")

Integrate as you wish with the rest of the script.